# How to await on a variable to change its value in Angular?

Tags: angular, async-await

I have a variable which changes its value upon an HttpRequest is completed. Its value is `false` unless the HttpRequest is finished. Is it possible to use it in a conditional statement? So far I have tried:

```
async getAsyncValue() {
    const loading = await this.dataSource.loading$.toPromise();
    if (!loading) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.dataSource.loading$.subscribe((data) => {
    //do something
}
```

Assuming the loading$ is an observable. You don't really need to convert it to a promise.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! Thank you!